SQLite, nextjs, typeorm pain of `id:null` for an insert to a table
Issue:

i got an AUTOINCREMENT, number field 'id' in my table (DB: sql-lite)
when i insert a partial row (no mandatory fields except primary key) i don't get the id value back from typeorm which was inserted in the DB
following in my setup and the multiple code i tried (check the service below)

entity definition
export class Requests {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  name: string;

...}

migration table
CREATE TABLE "requests" (
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      name varchar,
...);

in the service (issue here)
unable to get the auto-incremented value back despite create/insert/upsert/save... i need to know the id (primary key) of the row that was inserted

  public async saveRequest(passedPartialRequest: Partial<Requests> | any) {
    // case 1: if we don't provide an id, we get "TypeORMError: Cannot update entity because entity id is not set in the entity."
    // if we provide id:null or id:0, we get id: null or id:0 (even though the correct incremented id is created in the DB)
    const case1 = await this.requestsRepository.save({
      ...passedPartialRequest,
      id: null,
    });

    // case 2: inserted a row but id came back as undefined (from the DB)
    const case2 = await this.requestsRepository.create({
      passedPartialRequest,
    });

    // case 3: need to provide id, else we get "TypeORMError: Cannot update entity because entity id is not set in the entity."
    const case3 = await this.requestsRepository.insert({
      ...passedPartialRequest,
      id: null,
    });

    // case 4: TypeORMError: Cannot update entity because entity id is not set in the entity,
    // if we provide null, we get identifier: null
    const saved4 = await this.requestsRepository
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .insert()
      .values({
        ...passedPartialRequest,
        id: null,
      })
      .execute();

    // case 5: this also returns identifier: null - we need to provide id:null to prevent the TypeORMError above
    const case5 = await this.requestsRepository.upsert(
      { ...passedPartialRequest, id: null },
      ['id']
    );

    // case 6: OUTPUT or RETURNING clause only supported by Microsoft SQL Server or PostgreSQL or MariaDB databases.
    const case6 = await this.requestsRepository
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .insert()
      .into('requests')
      .values([passedPartialRequest])
      .returning('INSERTED.*')
      .printSql()
      .execute();    

